# C# Silverlight - How do I access a file that I set as a "resource"?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, resources, embedded-resource

I want to embed a dictionary file as a resource into my project so that it's part of the application instead of just a separate file. The function to load the dictionary will take either a URi or a string as the path to the file. (Example: `spellChecker.MainDictionary.LoadAsync(URiToMyDictionaryFile);`).

How do I access a file set as "resource" or "embedded resource"? Also, what' the difference between the two?

The goal is just to have the file as part of the application so I don't have to worry about making sure it's included when the app is distributed.

Thanks again!

-Sootah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between "Embedded Resource" and a "Resource" from Silverlight's point of view is that Silverlight can't access an "Embedded Resource" so don't use it.

To access a file added to the dll assembly as a "Resource" you need to add the name of the assembly plus ";component" as the first element of the Uri that accesses it:-

```
 spellChecker.MainDictionary.LoadAsync(new Uri("/yourProjectName;component/yourDictionary.dic",UriKind.Relative));
```

If you are building a XAP (that is you're not creating a Silverlight library) then have you considered using "Content" instead of "Resource".  This includes the file as part of the XAP alongside the dll rather than storing it in the dll.

Comment: For some odd reason it's still not working for me. I've added the file to the project, set it as a resource, and used the following code:

`Uri dctUri = new Uri("/SpellCheckTestPrj;component/C1Spell_en-US.dct", UriKind.Relative);
spellChecker.MainDictionary.LoadAsync(dctUri);`

But when attempting to load it like that it states that it can't be found. I coded the project to pop up a messagebox with the error that gets thrown, which I've posted a screenshot of here: http://www.tweaksforgeeks.com/shatner/DctLoadError.png

Images and whatnot that I reference in that manner in the XAML work fine.

Comment: Is the resource dictionary you are trying to load at the root of the project structure or is it inside a folder? For example, if your setup is something like SilverlightProject > ResourcesFolder > dictionary.xaml, the Uri becomes "SilverlightProject;component/ResourcesFolder/dictionary.xaml"